# gensim word2vec model.wv.index2word "TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method" in enumerate

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec, gensim, tensorboard, enumerate

I am using python3.5 and trying to repeat the code implemented in this video moment:

https://youtu.be/BkeQzJt0f5A?t=73

In the piece of code below "TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method" is happening:

```
with open("metadata.tsv", "w+") as file_metadata:
    for i,word in enumerate(model.wv.index2word[:max]):
        w2v[i] = model.wv[word]
        file_metadata.write(word + "\n")
```

How can I fix this to get the output from w2v like the video?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it is **max_size** not **max** in enumerate

```
max_size = len(model.wv.vocab) - 1
```